# Want to find degree of direction to rotate image in the map

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, core-location

I want to rotate bike on the map as per the direction of the route. I have put formula for that but image some time shows correctly on the path, some time not on the path. Please provide another formula to achieve the same thing, or make correction in this :

```
@interface MAViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
    CLLocation *previousLocation;
}

@end

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bike.png"];
    float fLat = degreesToRadians(previousLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    float fLng = degreesToRadians(previousLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    float tLat = degreesToRadians(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    float tLng = degreesToRadians(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    float degree = radiandsToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)));

    annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degree);

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    if  (!newLocation)
        return;

    currentLocation = newLocation;
    previousLocation = oldLocation;
    if(currentLocation != nil)
    {
        if (myAnnotation)
        {
            [self.myMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        }
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location title:@"Current Location" subTitle:nil];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in viewForAnnotation assumes that it will be called once when annotation is added (it's comparing outside "previous" and "current" values).  That delegate method can get called multiple times for the same annotation -- not just when it's added (eg. when user pans or zooms the map).  Code should probably just look at the "current" heading and apply the transform based only on that.  Also, you may want to apply the transform only to the image and not the whole annotationView (which will cause the callout to be rotated as well).

Comment: @Anna : How i can get current heading details ?

Comment: That should be in [currentLocation.course](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW25).